# Add Objects of different Types to ListAdapter

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I am building an Android Application, and I need to display information from different Objects in my ListAdapter.

E.g. I need to show patientName from Patient, and roomNumber from Room etc.

All my Objects are serialized from JSON-response(s).

At first I thought about creating a wrapper class, just for displaying the information in my List - but it seems like a crappy solution.

Like so:

```
public class ListOverviewWrapper {
    final String firstName;
    final String lastName;
    final int roomNumber;
    final String departmentName;
    ...
}
```

I can't seem to figure out, how to do this effectively. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would definitely recommend you to create a custom adapter for the `ListView`. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view

Comment: Yeah, I already have that as of now. But it gets a real pain when I need to reference the other Objects. To my understanding, you can't pass for example a List<Object> to the custom adapter, or?

Comment: you may refer to this too, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40394634/how-to-correctly-call-a-method-with-parameter-of-generic-type-and-get-rid-of-the.

Comment: Don't follow that link, create a wrapper as you said, and pass `List<ListOverviewWrapper>` to your custom adapter.